# Offset between click detection and button graphics in libgdx

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, controls

I have a libgdx application that contains a class `Button`. The constructor of `Button` takes three arguements: Filename of graphics, position, and game (the latter being used for callbacks of various sorts).

The button scales itself based on the graphics provided, thus setting its width and height based on the properties of the graphics.

The main class, `Game`, when a click is detected compares the coordinates of the click up against the coordinates of the button combined with its width and height.

Now, the main issue is that there is a little bit of a horizontal offset between the button and the click coordinates, so the effect is that the graphics show up a few pixels to the right of the clickable area. I cannot for the life of me figure out the source of this discrepancy, so I would greatly appreciate some fresh eyes to see where I'm going wrong here.

**Button, constructor and polling-method for clickable area.**

```
public Rectangle getClickArea() {
    return new Rectangle(pos.x - (img.getWidth() / 2), pos.y + (img.getHeight() / 2), w, h);
}

public Button(String assetfile, int x, int y, Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    img = new Pixmap(new FileHandle(assetfile));
    pos = new Vector2(x, y);
    this.w = img.getWidth();
    this.h = img.getHeight();
}
```

**A relevant snippet from InputHandler.** It listens for input and passes on the event. Please note that the vertical click position is subtracted from the vertical size of the screen, as vertical 0 is opposite in InputHandler:

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    tracker.click(screenX, Settings.windowSize_Y - screenY);
    return false;
}
```

**ClickTracker (referenced as `tracker` in the above snippet)**, the Class that does the actual comparison between clicks and clickables:

```
public void click(int x, int y) {
    Vector2 clickPos = new Vector2(x, y);
    for (Tickable c : world.getPaintables())
    {
        if (!(c instanceof Unit))
            continue;

         if (((Clickable)c).getClickArea().contains(clickPos)) {
             System.out.println("Clicked on unit");
         }


    }
    for (Clickable c : clickables)
    {
        if (c.getClickArea().contains(clickPos)) {
            c.clicked(x, y);
        }
    }
```

---

In short: The vertical alignment works as intended, but the horizontal is slightly off. The button graphics appear maybe around 10-20 pixels to the right of the clickable area.

I'll gladly post more info or code if needed, but I believe I have the relevant parts covered.

---

**Edit:**

As Maciej Dziuban requested, here's the snipped that draws the UI elements. `batch` is a `SpriteBatch` as provided by libgdx:

```
    for (Paintable p : ui) {
        batch.draw(new Texture(p.getImg()), p.getImgPos().x, p.getImgPos().y);
    }
```

the `getImgPos()` is an interface method implemented by all drawable items:

```
public Vector2 getImgPos() {
    return new Vector2(pos.x - (getImg().getWidth() / 2), pos.y);
}
```

It's worth noting that half of the horizontal image size is subtracted from the X pos, as X pos refers to the bottom center.

Comment: How do you draw your button? In `getClickArea()` it looks like `pos` represents center of the entity, while it's usually left-bottom corner.

Comment: @MaciejDziuban added as per your request.

Comment: `new Texture()` should not appear anywhere in your render loop. You're leaking multiple Textures on every frame, aside from needlessly loading many copies of the exact same texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistency in your position transformations:

- Your `clickArea`'s corner is `pos` translated by `[-width/2, height/2]` vector.
- Your `drawArea`'s corner is `pos` translated by `[-width/2, 0]` vector

They clearly should be the same, so if you want your `pos` to represent bottom-center of your entity (as you've explicitly stated) you have to change your `getClickArea()` method to, so it matches `getImgPos()`.

```
  public Rectangle getClickArea() {
      return new Rectangle(pos.x - (img.getWidth() / 2), pos.y, w, h);
  }
```

Side note: as Tenfour04 noticed, you create new texture each frame and this is **huge** memory leak. You should make it a field initialized in constructor or even a static variable given some buttons share the texture. Don't forget to call `dispose()` on resources. For more powerful asset management check out [this article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) (note it may be an overkill in small projects).

Comment: Adding `height/2` was a workaround for the fact that the clickable area becomes misaligned vertically without it. I have not found the reason why, but it works as intended with the workaround. The issue at hand is the horizontal allignment. +1 for optimization pointers regarding resource handling, as that is next on my todo-list.

Comment: Did you take a look at your camera/viewport setup? I used to get this kind of problems when I forgot to override `resize()` method in `ApplicationListener`.

Comment: You accepted my answer. Was it indeed camera issue?

Comment: While I haven't pinpointed it exactly, I believe that it is at least camera related. I use two PCs with a synced source-repository for developing, and I've found that the offset happens on only one of the PCs. The snippet you've posted is the discrepancy, and has to be modified depending on which PC I'm on, so that I get the vertical allignment correctly. The horizontal offset only happens on one of the PCs. I therefore conclude it must be down to the fact that the screens are different aspect ratios, resolutions, and sizes, as everything else remains the same.